# Discussion - Client Server Application architecture

Tags: architecture, .net-4.0, client-server

I want to develop a client-server based desktop application using .Net 4, C# and SQL Server.

Please refer to the image for what i am thinking about.
[image: Client Server Application Architecture]

There will be a server application accessing windows service or web service. The client application will have Multiple Document Interface.

Below are my points that what i am thinking about -

1. The client application will use socket connectivity with server application so as to get authenticated from server, and also to track record of client connections over server.
2. The service will be a web service
3. After successful authentication the client application will directly access web service so there will be no overloading on server.

I want your feedback on this whether it is a good way to implement or is there a better way? Should i use windows service instead of web service? Should i use socket connectivity for all data communication instead of directly consuming the web service?

Thank you for sharing your time and wisdom.

Regards

Irfan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most definitely use a web service boundary for all your client/server communications.

[WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) will do everything you want. You can expose multiple endpoints with [different bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733027.aspx), and even [customize what kind of security they use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731925.aspx).

Spend some time digging into the [WCF documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx) and I think you will find it is perfectly suited to your architecture diagram, and everything you need will be out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thanks Josh for your quick response. So you think this one is a perfect way, right?

Comment: I wouldn't say perfect. But if you are looking for building out a service oriented architecture on the .Net stack then WCF is the right tool for the job. WCF is a *BIG* technology though so spend the time to really dig in and you can make it sing for you.

Comment: That being said... if you have web based clients that are going to be consuming any of these services, then you will also want to spend some time looking at **ASP.Net Web API**. For simple REST/JSON calls it will be vastly simpler to use than WCF.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I am thinking about web service for future scope.

Comment: What about performance Josh? Do you think it will be having better performance than having socket data communication?

Comment: You can use net.tcp bindings with WCF... which is about as close as you are going to get to using raw sockets. Also, for service to service communication on the same machine, you can use Net Named Pipes, which is even faster than Socket.IO.

Again, the small overhead you will pay for WCF will be well worth the overall ease of development compared to trying to build all of that yourself.

Comment: that being said- WCF is a **very** complex subject, and has a very steep learning curve. If you can forgoe the extra stuff (different bindings / customize security) I would certainly recommend plain ol' web services, which are simpler by magnitudes.